# Run code in Background Worker

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, process, backgroundworker

I am trying to work with asp.net. 
I have very small question.
In one of my button click event, I have heavy task that need to be executed and it causing problem. How can i run this code in background worker. Any hint will be appreciated as i have no played with this background worker yet.

Here is the code for my background worker.

```
  protected void green_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string stdOut = null;
            string stdError = null;

            string address = "192.168.1.88";
            string user = "user";


            string pass = "testuser";
            SshExec ssh = new SshExec(address, user, pass);
            green_output.Text = "Connecting...";
            green_output.Text = "Connected";
            ssh.Connect();
            ssh.RunCommand("cfg_green " + green_textbox1.Text + " " + green_textbox2.Text + " " + green_textbox3.Text, ref stdOut, ref stdError);
            green_output.Text = stdOut;
            //green_output.Text = stdError;
            ssh.Close();
            // green_output.Text = "Disconnect";
        }
```

Comment: Is this code really realted to asp.net ? Or just wrong tag ?

Comment: Background worker in Web page? Maybe but browser will need to wait it completes...matbe you should describe your **root problem**

Comment: @Adriano Repetti, I have two buttons and I want both to run. Currently only one can be executed

Comment: It's Web app, not desktop...background worker is what you used in winforms but each request in ASP.net is parallel. Of course it needs to be completed before client see anything (unless you are using ajax). You need its output then you can't use a *run and forget* strategy. Make that event asynchronous client side with an AJAX POST.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, Thanks for you information, Could you please provide me with some sample code to accomplish this.

Comment: Just search for ajax post example. If already using jquery is few lines of code (but you have to expose a new WebMethod with code you now have in click handler)

Answer (score 0):

In general your question is a little to broad.
Not sure if you mean the background worker class which is aviable in WinForms (your tag indicates you mean asp.net 5). Do you really want to use exact this class ?

But i would recommend you to use tasks. See [MSDN Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)

There you can create and await tasks.

```
   var result = await Task.Run(() => myBackgroundWork());
```

Furthermore if your background code supports async  (e.g. network traffic) you could simplay await it and make your code asynchron without using threads.

See for example [Doing Work without threads](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/09/23/threadless) . 
Threads always come at a cost and you may not want to pay this.